# MulticastSocket can send but not receive

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm writing an Android app which communicates over a MulticastSocket. It's basically working fine, but I've come across a strange bug: Whenever the connection is interrupted and restored (e.g. the device losing WiFi connection briefly) the app can still send but not receive anything. When sending the other devices receive the packet, however when other devices send packets the device doesn't receive them.

I have verified that the receiver Thread is still up and and running. It's stuck in socket.receive. Adding a socket timeout didn't help, it just made the receives time out without receiving anything.

When I close and re-open the MulticastSocket everything works fine again. I have registered a BroadcastReceiver for connectivity changes which does a reconnect when the connection is lost and restored. This mitigates the problem a bit, but it still occurs when the connection is interrupted at another point (e.g. restarting the server).

So I either need to fix the socket.receive or reliably find out when the socket can't receive any more packets in order to close and re-open it. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
private MulticastSocket socket;

public void open() throws IOException {
    socket = new MulticastSocket(serverAddress.getPort());
    socket.joinGroup(serverAddress.getAddress());

    receiver = new Receiver();
    receiver.start();
}

private void send(MyPacket packet) throws IOException {
    if (socket == null)
        throw new IOException("Connection closed");

    DatagramPacket datagramPacket =
            new DatagramPacket(packet.getBuffer(), packet.getSize(), serverAddress);
    socket.send(datagramPacket);
}

private class Receiver extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!closing) {
            if (socket == null)
                return;

            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                close("IOException in receiver thread", e);
                return;
            }

            onPacketReceived(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that appears that Multicast support in Android is not as solid as some of use might hope. See http://codeisland.org/2012/udp-multicast-on-android/

Ie whether it actually works out or may be device dependent. It is not working on my Nexus5.

There are a number of bugs related to Multicast support on Android, but I suspect you are falling foul of https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1698

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect when the wifi goes down and up, I would suggest leaving and rejoining the group, rather than closing and re-opening the socket.